# Spring boot data connection is not released

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a batch job configured using an XML file. And I have created a new Spring boot application with dependency to this batch job. The purpose of this spring boot application is to run the batch job using an API (for testing purpose).
Let me share my implementation of the same.

batch-job-config.xml

```
<batch:job id="batch-job_update" parent="baseJob">
        <batch:step id="batch_update.step01">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk
                        reader="batchReader"
                        processor="batchProcessor"
                        writer="batchWriter"
                        commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

In the spring boot controller, I am running the batch job by loading this XML file into the context

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path/to/batch-job-config.xml");

Job job = context.getBean("batch-job_update, Job.class);
JobRepository jobRepository = context.getBean("jobRepositoryBeanName", JobRepository.class);
JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean("jobLauncherBeanName", JobLauncher.class);
jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job);
jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
JobParameters jobParameters = getJobParameters(jobParametersList);
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);

context.close();
```

The issue I am facing is that the db connections created while running the batch are not closed, and since I am running this API with lot of test cases, after the connections are exhausted I am getting the following exception

```
28-06-2022 10:01:38.476 [http-nio-7788-exec-3] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections)] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Could anyone please help me with this one? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating a new Spring application context for each request to your API. You can add the batch application context to your Spring Boot app and inject the job and job launcher in your controller instead, something like:

```
@RestController
public class JobLaunchingController {

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void launch(@RequestParam("name") String name) throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                        .addString("name", name)
                        .toJobParameters();
        this.jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    }
}
```

This will use the same database connection pool of the main application context which will be closed correctly when your Boot app is shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This will work, but I need this endpoint to run multiple batch jobs. So for example, if I need to run batch1, I'll call the /run-batch/batch1 (batch1 as a path parameter) end point and the corresponding xml for that batch will be loaded to the context. Could you please share your thoughts about this?

Comment: Okay I understood your suggestion. But I will need to load application context based on the batch job. So If I want to run batch1, then the batch job bean is defined in batch-job-config.xml. For batch2, its defined in batch-job-2-config.xml. (the batch jobs are modules in a spring batch repo). So I will need to load the application context based on the batch name path param. Do you know why the connection is not released when I close the context I loaded? or is there any other way to terminate/close the context?